# openRTSP problem

Tags: 14.04, rtsp

I am trying to save video stream from my IP camera to a `.mp4` file. Using openRTSP. The problem is that the duration of saved video file is always only two minutes. As a default, and also with options. If I set `<2` minutes (by key `-d`), writes as much as specified, if set `>2` minutes - still record exactly 2. I need video file with longer duration.

Saving stream:

```
openRTSP -4 -I rtsp://192.168.1.22:554//user=admin_password=_channel=1_stream=0.sdp > video.mp4
```

[This](http://guide.alibaba.com/shop/h-264-hd-1-0-mp-720p-mini-ip-security-network-camera-pinhole-3-6mm-lens-ir-web-cam-top-201-free-shipping_5197139.html) is the IP camera I am using:

Answer (score 3):

I have a very similar problem. According to [the help for openRTSP](http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/), you can use the -K command-line option to send an "OPTIONS" request to "remind" the server that we're waiting for data. However, when I try this, openRTSP tells me it's not supported.

I HAVE SOLVED THIS! (but Linux veterans will just roll their eyes and mutter something about Linux Administration Made Easy)

You need to build and install openRTSP. Uninstall `livemedia-utils` if you already have it installed (which you probably do)

```
sudo apt-get remove livemedia-utils
```

Otherwise you'll have two copies and might sometimes use the wrong one. This happened to me when I put my openRTSP scripts into `crontab` to run on reboot, or into `rc.local`. In both cases I also needed to specify the full path of openRTSP (after doing the below, it will be in `/usr/local/bin`)

From the terminal:

1. Run as root:

   ```
   sudo -i
   ```
2. Go to `/usr/src`:

   ```
   cd /usr/src
   ```
3. Get the live555 liveMedia source code:

   ```
   wget http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/public/live555-latest.tar.gz
   ```
4. Unpack it:

   ```
   tar -xzf live555-latest.tar.gz
   ```
5. Go into the directory that's just been unpacked:

   ```
   cd live
   ```
6. Generate the make files:

   ```
   ./genMakefiles linux
   ```
7. Build the code:

   ```
   make
   ```
8. Install the new version:

   ```
   make install
   ```
9. Stop being root:

   ```
   exit
   ```
10. Enjoy streaming with your camera.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem (2mins stream limit)! Camera gracefully closes rtsp connection (socket Received = 0)/
I tried `-O option`  (which means not to send OPTION command to the camera) - it HELPED!
I don't know why.